# How is table salt different from Neti-Pot salt?

Tags: salt

I purchased a neti-pot, which came with salt packets: how is this salt different from table salt?  Any reference or support is always appreciated

UPDATE:  My [Bayer HyrdraSense Nasal Rinse Kit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVkwHIH6NbA) salt packets contain MgCl NaCl, CaCl Na-Bicarbonate KCl. Instructions include boiling tap water and then cooling it to room temperature.

[image]

Comment: Mostly salt. I believe that they come in packets to ensure that they have a certain osmolarity/concentration. This insures that you do not dehydrate your mucous membranes.

Comment: Lack of iodine might be another answer, but we need to stop answering in comments.

Comment: Is that kit described anywhere online, and if yes, can you link to it? I added something at the beginning of my answer, anyway.

Comment: @Jan3  thanks for the questions.  Video link and photo added to OP

Comment: I explained that in my answer.

Comment: Equal parts table salt and baking soda works fine. Been using it for years as I have an oral problem from cancer.  Caution: It is very cheap and not exotic.

Answer (score 2):

MgCl NaCl, CaCl, Na-Bicarbonate, and KCl can be all found in sea water and therefore in [sea salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_salt), which means that this salt appears similar to sea salt, but it is obviously not natural sea salt because the description of [this HydraSense salt](https://www.hydrasense.ca/en/products/nasal-care/self-mix-nasal-care/netirinse/) says:

> The pre-measured and ready-to-mix salt packets contain: calcium
> chloride, magnesium chloride, potassium chloride, sodium bicarbonate
> and sodium chloride. **Ingredients are not naturally sourced.**

From this it's not clear if even NaCl itself is artificially produced or maybe they used sea or rock salt, purified it and added the mentioned ingredients.

Other sources ([University of Missouri-Kansas City](https://info.umkc.edu/studenthealth/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Neti-pot-07012014.pdf), [Brown University](http://web.archive.org/web/20190126045544/https://www.brown.edu/campus-life/health/services/sites/brown.edu.campus-life.health.services/files/Sinus%20Irrigation%2016.pdf)) say that **un-iodized salt (canning, kosher, pickling, or sea salt)** can be used for Neti-Pot. This means salt without iodine, anti-caking agents (such as calcium silicate) or anything else added, which can be then mixed with baking soda (Na bicorbonate). So, "table salt" which typically contains iodine, anti-caking agents and other stuff should not be used. On [Family Practice Notebook](https://fpnotebook.com/ent/pharm/nslsln.htm) they say iodine can affect the function of small hair (cilia) in the respiratory tract. For the actual saline solution to be as little irritant to the nose as possible, it should be isotonic, that is 0.9% (9 g NaCl in 1 liter of water).

I've found 4 reviews, all of which say that nasal irrigation with Neti-Pot may be useful for chronic sinusitis and some other conditions in the upper respiratory tract without any significant side effects:

- [American Family Physician, 2009](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2778074/)
- [PeerJ, 2019](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6542345/)
- [International Journal of Environmental Research and Public Health, 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5451967/)
- [Cochrane, 2016](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD011995.pub2/abstract)

I have found no convincing evidence to say that certain "special" salt, which can be expensive, is better than table salt.

Answer (score 0):

Table salt contains additional unwanted ingredients.

**What is neti-salt?**

First link to vendor appearing in a websearch selling overpriced salt says:

> Ingredients: Pharmaceutical grade sodium chloride (99.99%) USP.
>   Directions: Place a heaping 1/4 teaspoon in your Neti Pot and add warm water.

That is not to say that vendors opting for the name 'neti' aren't willing to also add 'exotic' stuff, that's then not beneficial either.

**Regular kitchen table salt can be used but will cause problems because of all the additives.**

Apart from possible unknown adulterations when using "funny" salts ('Himalaya' etc)  just the usually [allowed anti-caking agents for example are:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticaking_agent)

341 tricalcium phosphate
460(ii) powdered cellulose
470b magnesium stearate
500 sodium bicarbonate
535 sodium ferrocyanide
536 potassium ferrocyanide
538 calcium ferrocyanide
542 bone phosphate (i.e. Calcium phosphate)
550 sodium silicate
551 silicon dioxide
552 calcium silicate
553a magnesium trisilicate
553b talcum powder
554 sodium aluminosilicate
555 potassium aluminium silicate
556 calcium aluminosilicate
558 bentonite
559 aluminium silicate
570 stearic acid
900 polydimethylsiloxane

Some of these are listed in the Eu as E170, E504, E535, E536, E551, E559…

> [Table salt](https://sci-toys.com/ingredients/table_salt.html)
>
> Table salt is sodium chloride combined with iodine sources (for nutrition), stabilizers for the iodine, and anti-caking compounds to make it pour by preventing it from absorbing water from the air.

So supermarket bought regular table salt can be quite a bit too irritating for a nasal irrigation. Depending on jurisdiction not all ingredients have to be listed on table salt.

> Nasal irrigation is based on warm saline solution, i.e. salt dissolved in lukewarm tap water. ... However, chemical anti-caking (aka “free-flowing”) additives used in common table salt (e.g. sodium silicoaluminate) produce an unpleasant burning sensation in the nose and are not advised medically or by Yoga instructors.
>   <sub>–– [The problems of salt for neti - NetiNext](https://www.erp4it.com/netinext/2011/04/the-focus-of-this-post-is-on-neti-as-a-regular-practice-in-the-american-bathroom-and-the-related-economic-and-usability-issu.html)</sub>
>
> anti-caking agents or preservatives (these can be irritating to the nasal lining)
>   <sub>–– [SALINE SINUS RINSE RECIPE 2019 American Academy of Allergy, Asthma & Immunology.](https://www.aaaai.org/conditions-and-treatments/library/allergy-library/saline-sinus-rinse-recipe)</sub>

With just a little chemistry knowledge anyone can conclude: among other things nasal irrigation is used for reducing mucus viscosity. This is clearly not an outcome achieved if adding bentonite into a solution for the nasal cavity. While listed as [non-toxic non-irritating](https://digitalfire.com/4sight/hazards/ceramic_hazard_bentonite_toxicity_31.html), bentonite is used as cat litter, and hence it does in the nose what it does in the litter box: increases viscosity of mucus. This effect is there for all anti-caking agents. Some are directly irritating the membranes, all are doing the opposite of what one wants to achieve.

For the US salt for use in organic products:

**Common anti-caking/free-flow agents that are allowed in the US table salt include:**

> • Calcium silicate
>   • Ferric ammonium citrate
>   • Sodium ferrocyanide
>   • Magnesium silicate
>   • Magnesium carbonate
>   • Propylene glycol
>   • Aluminum calcium silicate
>   • Sodium aluminosilicate
>
> [USDA organic regulations (PDF)](https://www.ams.usda.gov/sites/default/files/media/7%20Salt%20and%20Preservatives%20FINAL%20RGK%20V2.pdf)

Ordinary table salts may still contain (sodium and magnesium carbonate (E 500, E 504), sodium-, potassium- and calcium ferrocyanides (E 535, E 536, E 538), [silicon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide), calcium- and magnesium silicates (E 551 – E 553), [iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrous_tartrate) [tartrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartrate) (E 534). Aluminium salts are officially no longer allowed in Europe as an additive, but can be a [found](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2782734/) in [some](https://www.nutritionmyths.com/aluminum-in-table-salt/) [salts](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/photo-stories/table-salt-can-be-poisonous/photostory/64385362.cms).

[Additives List, E numbers in Numerical Order, Food Safety of Ireland, 2019.](https://www.fsai.ie/faq/additives/list.html)

---

Main sources for bacterial contamination are neither the salts nor the water. Preparing a too large portion of solution in advance and letting it sit, and the pots used themselves are:

> **Although common and frequently based on potentially dangerous bacteria, contamination *is considered a false problem by some experts.* They think that the nasal cavity is naturally full of bacteria and the addition of new pathogens is not clinically relevant.**
>
> The problem of sterility of the solutions and devices has been debated.
>
> **Solutions are at risk of contamination when large volumes of solution based on distilled water, bottled water, or boiled water are prepared at home, maintained in containers** and used each time when NI is needed by withdrawing the required amount of liquid. Devices can be contaminated when they are continuously used without adequate cleaning. Lee et al. reported that **after one and two weeks of use, irrigation bottles** used by adults undergoing endoscopic sinus surgery that were washed with hot soapy water after each use **were found to be contaminated by a large spectrum of bacteria, including Pseudomonas aeruginosa, Serratia marcescens, Proteus mirabilis, and Staphylococcus aureus**. Similar findings were reported by other authors and, because in many cases contaminating bacteria were the same as those that could cause acute rhinosinusitis, it was suggested that the main source of device colonization was the sinonasal cavities. The risk of contamination seems independent of the type of device. Additionally, the use of a one-way valve irrigation bottle, theoretically capable of reducing the risk of reflux of contaminated solution in the device, was found to be practically ineffective. In contrast, contamination seems to be influenced by the composition of the solution. It was shown that acidic, isotonic saline solutions were more frequently associated with bacterial contamination probably because some of the most common contaminants grow optimally in similar environmental conditions. Finally, contamination was found more frequently with longer durations of NI use. With some exceptions, studies have reported that both bottles and bulb syringes were contaminated after one to two weeks of use in approximately 25% of the cases and in 45% after four weeks.
>
> <sub>–– Nicola Principi & Susanna Esposito: ["Nasal Irrigation: An Imprecisely Defined Medical Procedure"](https://dx.doi.org/10.3390%2Fijerph14050516), Int J Environ Res Public Health. 2017 May; 14(5): 516. doi: 10.3390/ijerph14050516 PMCID: PMC5451967
>   PMID: 28492494</sub>

Comment: Good Lord, don't recommend tap water for nasal irrigation. Potable water safe for drinking and hand washing still contains contaminates that can cause serious problems if forced up the nasal passages

Comment: I assumed that the question comes from India - this is why I'm sceptical to think fresh tap water would be OK. I do agree that Na Cl, as clean as possible, should be used, because you never know what's really in the table salt.

Comment: Wikipedia says that kosher salt may contain anti-caking agents. [Indiamart](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/non-iodized-sea-salt-19733826197.html) sells sea salt without iodine or anything else added, but it likely contains a lot of natural things other than NaCl, so I'm not sure what to think - would it be OK for irrigation or not.

Comment: Actually @LangLangC it's not paranoia, medical professionals recommend to use boiled/cooled water OR distilled water. Besides high levels of chlorine and other contaminants that are processed differently via GI tract than if absorbed directly into nasal vasculature, there have been (albeit only a few, but rather serious) cases of brain infections by local municipal water parasites and fungi.  The venous drainage of the nasal and sinus passageways is in the "danger triangle" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_triangle_of_the_face

Comment: At least one of those cases was in the USA, btw, so it's not just a "third world" problem.  Yes lots of people use tap water, but we can't say it's safe.

Comment: Two cases from Louisiana /US: [Primary amebic meningoencephalitis deaths associated with sinus irrigation using contaminated tap water](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22919000/)

Comment: Searching the net in other languages than English paints a clear picture to me, regions with clean water supply say fresh lukewarm water, directly from tap. Again: that is not me recommending anything. But as also shown in the quote I used, absolute sterility is not needed and childishly incomplete thinking if people prepare solutions in advance or use improperly cleaned, biofilm infested pots (and most have dysfunctional constructions anyway).

Comment: Neti-pot is popular in India and a lot of Indians may read this. [CDC](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/page/food-water-safety) recommends to travellers: "In most developing countries, tap water should probably not be drunk, even in cities." So, if it's risky to drink, it's even riskier to irrigate the nose with it. I'm aware that people become resistant to bacteria...I don't feel the need to argue about American tap water, but Indian tap water is just not the same and I'm not sure if you can ignore this. And bottled water can be fine, so no boiling needs to be included, really.

Comment: OP = USA East coast,  **not** India

Comment: @gatorback, OK. The discussion went with all the readers from around the world in mind.

Comment: @LangLangC Sorry if that came across negatively, I didn't read it that you were recommending anything unsafe. I was just clarifying that it's not a "paranoia" but actual medical recommendations based on exceedingly rare but serious complications that have occurred.  I've worked with 7 different ENT or allergist specialists and have read the data on those super-rare events.

Comment: Plus FWIW I irrigate now and then myself and I was instructed by the specialists I saw to use distilled water.  It's probably overkill, but not a huge inconvenience.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Thx, and never mind. As a site we do not recommend anything, per policy principle, I thought. But we see that violated by now constantly, albeit tolerated, undermining policy enough to misread this A quickly. Here, I was talking as per Q scope about *salinity* of tap water and that irrigation 'works' with hypo, iso and (mild) hypertonic water, main difference being the discomfort experienced for 'significantly' non-iso and long term downsides for that practice. Some read the Q as "What should I put up my nose?"/Bonus: check different WPs, like ja,da,de,fr… and then ru!